# Why does the UDP port become blocked forever when my program terminates?

Tags: qt, sockets

Sometimes when my application exits, the UDP port it listens on cannot be reused. The only solution is it reboot the machine before restarting the application.

Netstat doesn't show any applications using the UDP port.

```
>netstat -apn | grep 9988
udp 0 0.0.0.0:9988 0.0.0.0:*
```

I am using Qt's [QUdpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html) class.

Comment: are you closing the port? You'll need to show us your UDP port code to diagnose this.

Comment: if you wait long enough your udp stack will free/clear the port - but the length of time for that can be substantial.

Comment: Seems like the wait must be hours

Comment: Please check that your application is really closed, including all threads and all child processes which got forked by the application (and their childs). I would suggest that something still has the socket open.